# qemu-img dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/nettle/lib/libnettle.6.dylib

Tags: macos, qemu

I am trying to convert an image with `qemu-img` from VHDX to qcow2 on macOS 11.3.1 yet I get the following error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/nettle/lib/libnettle.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/qemu-img
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I have installed `qemu` using homebrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was solved simply by reinstalling qemu using homebrew with the following:

```
brew reinstall qemu
```